# safari cannot open the page because too many redirects occurred wordpress

Tags: iphone, wordpress

safari cannot open the page because too many redirects occurred (website is in wordpress).
All other pages are working perfectly fine, only the main page (homepage) is having this trouble. I have cleared all the cookies, cache & history from iphone, still the same problem. Any help?

Comment: There can be a lot possible reasons for this and without looking at URL, it'd just be a wild guess. First thing first, try disabling all plugins and see if that helps.

Comment: disabled all the plugins, still the same problem.

Comment: Is this just happening in Safari? Have you checked the homepage in other browsers?

Comment: chrome also having the same issue. Cleared all cookies, cache from both safari and chrome, didn't work. On desktop , it's working perfectly fine after clearing cookies, cache. But on mobile still having a problem. :(

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by using following method in .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}  !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

is causing the error. use

> RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$

to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into .htaccess file.

I've had a simple redirect write in .htaccess that was preventing to be loaded on Safari. As such:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```